# What can you put into a media query expression?

Tags: css, media-queries

In the following media query the styles defined in the style declaration will be applied when viewing via screen AND when the minimum width is 480px wide (correct?):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    #leftsidebar {width: 200px; float: left;}
    #main {margin-left:216px;}
}
```

What else can you put into that expression statement?

For example, I would like to condition on the URL fragment:

```
@media screen and (document.location.hash=="#about") {
    #leftsidebar {width: 200px; float: left;}
    #main {margin-left:216px;}
}

@media screen and (document.location.hash=="#services") {
    #leftsidebar {width: 200px; float: left;}
    #main {margin-left:216px;}
}

@media screen and (document.location.hash=="#contact") {
    #leftsidebar {width: 200px; float: left;}
    #main {margin-left:216px;}
}
```

Comment: You would need JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can you put into a media query expression?

You can only put a media feature. The only available media features are documented in the spec ([MQ3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1), [MQ4](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-4)).

> For example, I would like to condition on the URL fragment:

That's unfortunately not possible with media queries, though that does sound like an interesting use case without having to resort to applying the URL fragment to the `html` or `body` or some other arbitrary wrapper element. I'm not sure how well it would jive with media queries though, given that the URL fragment isn't part of the device media *per se*, but a part of the URL. This feature would be better suited in its own at-rule (such as the now-gone `@document`) or as part of Selectors.

The closest pure-selector alternative I can think of (prepending `:root:has(#about:target)`, `:root:has(#services:target)`, etc to every selector) is in Selectors 4 and not even available to CSS, so that's a real bummer.

Comment: That `@document` rule is what I've been looking for, https://www.quackit.com/css/at-rules/css_document_at-rule.cfm. It looks like it was deferred from CSS3 to CSS4.